# Trying to use Axios to GET request localhost on native react but getting a unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error

Tags: reactjs, request, axios, native, es6-promise

Error im recieveing in the console.log

[14:02:02] [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:24 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:87:25 in handleError
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import PhotoSection from './photo-section';
//functional is just returning some data - static
//smart component for dynamic class component
export default class PhotoFeed extends Component {

  render() {
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/photos')
        .then(response=> console.log(response));
      return (
      <View>
        <Text> textInComponent </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It most likely means 127.0.0.1:3000/photos isnt responding.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound is it because the localhost on my pc is different then the one im using in expo?

Comment: @SpeedOfRound that was the issue, thank you :)